# Android app provide view to another

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to fill a container view in my app with a view from another app.

The host application (my app) would use views specifically provided for it from the other apps. Think of something similar to Samsung's launcher + Flipboard, or the Google Now Launcher + Google Now - a part of the application, a whole view area, provided by another package.

What would be the preferred way of creating an SDK of some sort? Is there a fix pattern for doing so, or is this an uncharted territory of Android development, or outright forbidden by the way apps work?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use the desired app API to fetch data into your app and then display it on your container.

Not exactly what you asked for but it can go as a workaround for this case.

Comment: Because I do not want to add specific apps to mine as displays, I want the users to be able to download plugins/modules that provide specific views. Something like the widget system.

Comment: I guess you can proceed by adding a small plugins manager into your app, starting with your own implementation of small amount of plugins through API and exceeding them with time.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a way to fill a container view in my app with a view from another app.

As written, that is not possible.

> Think of something similar to Samsung's launcher + Flipboard, or the Google Now Launcher + Google Now - a part of the application, a whole view area, provided by another package.

Neither of those involve "fill[ing] a container view in my app with a **view** from another app" (emphasis added), as that is not possible. A view (i.e., a subclass of `View`) cannot be passed across process boundaries.

Most likely, what you are seeing are other apps launching dialog-themed activities (i.e., activities with a theme that does not fill the screen).

Or, since these are launchers, perhaps you are seeing app widgets, with the launcher providing the app widget host, and the app widget defining the UI by means of a `RemoteViews` structure.

What is theoretically possible, — but terribly unreliable given multi-window, navigation, etc. — would be for the "host" app to tell the "UI-supplying" app to draw some content on the screen at a particular pixel coordinate, perhaps through some floating window.

Comment: would it really be possible to for the "host" app to ask another app to draw something within certain boundaries?

Comment: Yes, the widget system is a great (and possibly better understood) example of what I'm trying to achieve here. But instead of resizable, etc. views, I have a fixed container (say, a card) that fills the whole screen and allows the "provider" app to fill it with content. RemoteViews might just be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @lelloman: The host could use an explicit `Intent` as a broadcast, or a method on a bound service exposed by the UI-supplying app, to say "please draw stuff at these pixel coordinates". However, the host cannot provide a drawing surface on which the UI-supplying app could do that. The UI-supplying app would have to handle that itself (e.g., a floating window), and that causes all sorts of coordination problems on screen rotations/other configuration changes, navigation, and related scenarios. Android is not well-suited for that pattern.

Comment: @fonix232: "I have a fixed container (say, a card) that fills the whole screen and allows the "provider" app to fill it with content" -- what is the advantage of doing that versus having the provider app just display an activity?

Comment: @CommonsWare it wouldn't be a single view that is displayed, I'm thinking more of a horizontally scrolling list of containers here. So multiple providers, multiple views, displayed in a single "line". Think of it like widgets that take up the whole screen.

Comment: @fonix232: You are certainly welcome to roll your own `RemoteViews`-based system. The UI will be fairly limited, just as the UI of app widgets is fairly limited. See [this pair of sample projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RemoteViews) for the basics.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Android, mostly because it would be not secure. You could request view from another app and then read the data.

There are several situations where something like this happens:

1. **Launcher widgets**. But it is your app which gives out the data to display.
2. **Split screen**. You can allow it for your app, but you have no control over what is on the other part of the screen.

All of these are platform-level and you do not have access to such features. Some OEMs, like Samsung, introduce things like this, but this is not mainstream.

So the best approach would be to have app A send specific data to app B and then app B displays this data in the desired manner.

Comment: Okay, let's see a more concrete example. Say, I want a launcher of my own writing, and I want the Google Now screen to be part of it. Since it is an unlicensed SDK, and only a reverse-engineered version of it exists for the public, I can't put that into an app that goes on the Play Store. But I could whip up an interface that allows other apps to provide the view (like widgets), and upload only the core launcher to the Play Store, allowing users to install the GNow panel separately.

Comment: No you can not and this was a huge problem for the guy who made Nova Launcher. He did it somehow, but I think it is done with a special transition. In general, you can not do Google Now slide-in in your launcher. You probably could on a root device, but not on a stock one

Comment: Actually you can, but it is not what I want to achieve. What I want is, something like the widget system. User can select from a list which app's view to display, and the app's single provided view appears in a container (say, a CardView, or anything, really).

Comment: As I said, programmers being able to do something like this would be a huge security risk. There is the multi-window feature, which theoretically allows apps to be opened inside windows on top of others, but it requires root to enable on non-compatible devices and does not give you control over when and how the windowed app appears :(